# Binding of a ComboBox SelectedIndex to a ListView ItemsSource

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm, combobox, viewmodel

I have a `ComboBox` that contain `int` values between 1-4, and a `ListView` that contain a certain `ItemTemplate`.
I'm trying to recreate `ListView` rows according to the user's selection.
So if He selects 1 there will be 1 row, if he selects 3 there will be 3 rows, etc.
Here is my code:

Xaml:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<ComboBox Name="cbNumOfUnits" Width="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding Numbers}" SelectedIndex="{Binding NumberOfDevices}" >
</ComboBox>

<ListView Margin="10" Name="lvDataBinding" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" BorderBrush="Transparent">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <WrapPanel>
                <Label Name="lbldeviceName" Width="100" Content="{Binding Name}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="5,5,0,0" />
                <xctk:MaskedTextBox x:Name="_maskedTextBox" Width="100" Text="{Binding Address}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Mask="000.000.000.000"  />
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

ViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace App3
{
public class ViewModel
{ 
    private ItemHandler _itemHandler;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        _itemHandler = new ItemHandler();
        _itemHandler.Add( new Item() { Name = "Master", Address = "" } );
        numberOfDevices = 1;
        OnPropertyChanged( "NumberOfDevices" );

        numbers = new ObservableCollection<int>();

        for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
        {
            numbers.Add( i + 1 );
        }
    }


    ObservableCollection<int> numbers;
    public ObservableCollection<int> Numbers 
    {
        get { return numbers; }
        set
        { 
            OnPropertyChanged( "Numbers" );
        }
    }


    public List<Item> items;
    public List<Item> Items
    {
        get { return _itemHandler.Items; }
    }


    private int numberOfDevices = 1;
    public int NumberOfDevices
    {
        get
        {
            return numberOfDevices;
        }
        set
        {
            if( value != numberOfDevices )
            {
                numberOfDevices = value;

                string name = null;


                _itemHandler = new ItemHandler();

                for( int i = 0; i < numberOfDevices + 1; i++ )
                {
                    if( i == 0 )
                    {
                        name = "Master";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        name = "Slave" + i;
                    }

                    _itemHandler.Add( new Item() { Name = name, Address = "" } );
                }


                OnPropertyChanged( "NumberOfDevices" ); 
            }
        }

    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged( string propertyName )
    {
        if( null != PropertyChanged )
        {
            PropertyChanged( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( propertyName ) );
        }
    }

}



public class Item
{ 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}



public class ItemHandler
{
    public ItemHandler()
    {
        Items = new List<Item>();
    }

    public List<Item> Items { get; private set; }

    public void Add( Item item )
    {
        Items.Add( item );
    }
} 

}
```

My questions are:

1. Why isn't my `ComboBox` start with 1 in the `SelectedIndex` as deafult, I set the numberOfDevices to 1.
2. Changing the `ComboBox` `SelectedIndex` enters the ViewModel, the `ListView` items seems to be built but they are no presented in the GUI.
   It looks like  `get { return _itemHandler.Items;}` only occur in the start and the code don't reenter there again.

Thanks.

Comment: Never use SelectedIndex. It's a horrible pain in the ass. Always use SelectedItem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you fix the following issues in your code, it will work:

1. Your `ViewModel` doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`
2. Instead of binding to `SelectedIndex`, you should bind to `SelectedItem`. Since the `SelectedIndex` is 0 based and your `SelectedItem` starts on 1, the second item was selected by default.
3. When the `NumberOfDevices` property changes, you don't notify that the `Items` property has changed. You can fix this by adding the `OnPropertyChanged("Items");` after `OnPropertyChanged("NumberOfDevices");`